# What's the translation of "talk move" in French?

Tags: traduction

Talk moves [refer to](https://talkmoves.com/):

> discussion strategies to promote equitable participation in a rigorous classroom learning environment. Teachers and students can both use Talk Moves to encourage participation and engagement with math content and reasoning.

What's the translation of "talk move" in French?

Google translate and DeepL didn't help.

Comment: It feels very much "user facing". To you does the collocation feel similar to dance move or a move when playing a game?

Answer (score 2):

There is a term that has been in use for already quite some time in France, and that would for the least be a fairly good approximation to the type of dicussion implied, which is still not the term needed; that is "*discussion raisonnée*".

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22discussion%20raisonn%C3%A9e%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

[image]

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/raisonn%C3%A9)) **raisonné** **2.** [Dans le domaine de l'expr., notamment dans le cadre d'exposés écrits, de publications à caractère didact.] Qui prouve par le raisonnement; qui est accompagné de commentaires, d'explications. Analyse, description, méthode raisonnée; exposé, extrait, recueil raisonné; catalogue raisonné d'une œuvre; arithmétique, dictionnaire, grammaire raisonné(e).
> • Je lui ferais apprendre (...) la géographie détaillée et raisonnée (Taine, Notes Paris, 1867, p. 298).
> • Il réserva plusieurs heures chaque après-midi à des lectures raisonnées dont il rédigeait un compte rendu (Martin du G., Devenir, 1909, p. 81).V. anomalie ex. 4, classer ex. 4:

([ref. 1: Les méthodes de travail de Gersonide et le maniement du savoir scolastique](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_m%C3%A9thodes_de_travail_de_Gersonide_et/g_xnvq6FozIC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22discussion+raisonn%C3%A9e%22&pg=PA136&printsec=frontcover)) Le but est de déterminer la réponse correcte , de trouver la vérité – ou d'enseigner cette vérité au moyen d'une discussion raisonnée . L'outil de la dialectique est utilisé dans cette perspective .

([ref. 2: Faire participer les habitants ?: Citoyenneté et pouvoir dans les quartiers populaires](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Faire_participer_les_habitants/HV0cCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22discussion+raisonn%C3%A9e%22&pg=PA96&printsec=frontcover)) Les institutionnels étaient d'emblée dans le registre de la chose publique, considérant leur exposé comme support pour une discussion raisonnée avec les habitants.

([ref. 3: La prothèse totale de hanche dans tous ses états](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_proth%C3%A8se_totale_de_hanche_dans_tous/09bWDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22discussion+raisonn%C3%A9e%22&pg=PA49&printsec=frontcover) ) Instaurer une discussion raisonnée dans un débat passionnel est une tâche difficile. Des controverses existent depuis la description des différentes voies d'abord de hanche, c'est-à-dire depuis l'année 1882 où a été décrite la voie de ...

([ref. 4: Etre soi avec Heidegger](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Etre_soi_avec_Heidegger/136aDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22discussion+raisonn%C3%A9e%22&pg=PA86&printsec=frontcover) ) Nous en trouvons des exemples à travers les débats télévisés organisés autour d'un thème précis qui réunit alors des experts dont on attend une discussion raisonnée au service de la vérité. Le bavardage, quant à lui, ne nécessite pas de ...

So, a translation by combination could be "*pratiques de discussion raisonnée*".

(([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pratique)) **pratique C. −1.** Manière habituelle d'agir, comportement habituel.)